# Exclude specific directory for take base_media_url value? (Tainted canvases may not be exported)

Tags: magento2.3, admin, media, cdn

I configured a CDN on my Magento site, and on admin, I configured the **base_static_url** and the **base_media_ur**l with the CDN Url on **Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs**. These works fine mostly, and the images and the static content is displayed without a problem.

The problem is with one custom module that needs to upload an image on the server, stored it, and get it this show it. But this process throws me the error:

> Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases
> may not be exported

And this only happened in production, where we have the CDN configured. Reviewing a little about this error con google, we saw that some people mentioned that, in fact, this could be caused by the use of different domains. Is there some way to exclude some specific directory to take the file from the default base URL instead of the custom CDN URL?

Thanks.